# how do I export my pose with my character

Tags: rigging

[image]

I want my character in this pose but when i export her and put her in the game i want her in she goes back into the t-pose. What can I do to fix this.

Comment: You could either create a keyframe on all her bones and export the action as well, or apply the Armature modifier so that she keeps this pose (but make sure that you've made a copy before applying the modifier)